# In vim how to select "until the end of the function" for C-like languages?

Tags: vim

Say the cursor is at the asterisk:

```c
void foo(int n) {
  int i;
  // the cursor is here: *
  for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
    bar(i);
  }
}
```

What's the easiest way to perform an operator until the end of the function? If I run `dΩ`, when `Ω` is this operator, I'd expect to see:

```c
void foo(int n) {
  int i;
  // the cursor is here:* 
}
```

That is, everything from that point to the end of the function is deleted. I know about `di{`, but that would delete the entire function.

Comment: I didn't know that existed. I don't have enough rep to move this however.

Answer (score 3):

Check in [`:h object-motions`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#object-motions):

- [`:h ]]`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#%5D%5D)
- [`:h ][`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#%5D%5B)

Comment: This is great to know, thanks! But I was looking for something that worked until the end of the function. Its unlikely to be a problem in C, but in C++: if I had a namespace -> class -> method hierarchy and I ran `d][` in the method, it'd delete everything upto the namespace(first column).

Answer (score 2):

For C, Vim already provide ways to do that natively.

In C++, there are corner cases with functions defined within a class definitions - in these cases, the function definition is not 0-indented, and Vim doesn't know how to handle the detection function boundaries.

Some scripting is required. On vi.SE, I did [describe a solution](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/7942/626) that I've integrated through 2 plugins I'm maintaining (lh-dev + lh-tags).

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use a RegEx:

```
d/^}<CR>
```

That is: *delete until the line starting with "}"*.